# Numpy array shape not recognized as int by numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I want to generate a numpy matrix based on some arrays and accelerate this generation using `jit`, or ideally `njit`. It keeps sending the 2 following warnings if `nopython=False` (with `nopython` enabled it fails) which I cannot understand:

> :14: NumbaWarning:  Compilation is
> falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function
> "process_stuffs" failed type inference due to: No conversion from
> array(int32, 2d, C) to array(int64, 2d, A) for 'inp', defined at None
>
> File "", line 23: def
> process_stuffs(output,inp,route1, route2, zoneidx):
>
> ```
> input_pallets, _ = inp.shape
> ^
> ```
>
> During: typing of argument at  (23)
>
> File "", line 23: def
> process_stuffs(output,inp,route1, route2, zoneidx):
>
> ```
> input_pallets, _ = inp.shape
> ^
> ```
>
> @jit(nopython=False, :14:
> NumbaWarning:  Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT
> looplifting enabled because Function "process_stuffs" failed type
> inference due to: Cannot determine Numba type of <class
> 'numba.core.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>
>
> File "", line 25: def
> process_stuffs(output,inp,route1, route2, zoneidx):
>
> ```
> for minute in range(input_pallets):
> ^
> ```
>
> @jit(nopython=False,
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\dev38\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:151:
> NumbaWarning: Function "process_stuffs" was compiled in object mode
> without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

Although it is true the function use complex types, it fails at the **very** beginning while determining the length of the `inp` array, and then it doesn't want to generate a loop although I have seen plenty of examples.

I tried to correct the error by specificying the types using `locals`, but as you can see it doesn't help.

This is a minimal working code :

```
zoneidx=Dict.empty(key_type=types.unicode_type,value_type=types.int8)
zoneidx["A"]=np.int8(0)
zoneidx["B"]=np.int8(1)
zoneidx["C"]=np.int8(2)
zoneidx["D"]=np.int8(3)
zoneidx["E"]=np.int8(4)


output = np.zeros(shape=(110,5),dtype=np.int64)
inp = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,2))
route1 = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'),size=10)
route2 = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'),size=10)

@jit(nopython=False,
     locals={'input_pallets':numba.int64,
             'step':numba.int64,
             'inp':numba.types.int64[:,:],
             'route1':numba.types.unicode_type[:],
             'route2':numba.types.unicode_type[:],
             'output':numba.types.int64[:,:]})
def process_stuffs(output,inp,route1, route2, zoneidx):

    input_pallets, _ = inp.shape

    for minute in range(input_pallets):
        prod1, prod2 = inp[minute]
        if prod1+prod2 <1:
            continue

        if prod1:
            routing = route1
            number_of_pallets = prod1
            number_of_steps = route1.shape[0]
        else:
            routing = route2
            number_of_pallets = prod2
            number_of_steps = route2.shape[0]
        for step in range(number_of_steps):
            zone = routing[step]
            output[minute+step,zoneidx[zone]]+=number_of_pallets

    return output




numba.__version__ == 0.53.1
numpy.__version__ == 1.19.2
```

What is wrong with my code?

NB: I am not interested in the correctness of my code output, I know that "route2" will be ignored as soon as "route1" is activated by "inp". I just want it to be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message is misleading. In fact the types of the inputs were indeed not correctly given, it had nothing to do with the `.shape` method.

My solution was to use the `numba.typeof` function to tell it what types to expect. E.g. an int32 was expected, not 64 for "inp". And "unichr" was expected, not unicode.

Here is the working version of my minimal example:

```
zoneidx=Dict.empty(key_type=numba.typeof(route1).dtype,value_type=types.int8)
zoneidx["A"]=np.int8(0)
zoneidx["B"]=np.int8(1)
zoneidx["C"]=np.int8(2)
zoneidx["D"]=np.int8(3)
zoneidx["E"]=np.int8(4)


output = np.zeros(shape=(110,5),dtype=np.int64)
inp = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,2))
route1 = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'),size=10)
route2 = np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'),size=10)

@jit(nopython=False,
     locals={'input_pallets':numba.int64,
             'step':numba.int64,
             'inp':numba.types.int32[:,:],
             'route1':numba.typeof(route1),
             'route2':numba.typeof(route1),
             'output':numba.types.int64[:,:]})
def process_stuffs(output,inp,route1, route2, zoneidx):

    input_pallets, _ = inp.shape

    for minute in range(input_pallets):
        prod1, prod2 = inp[minute]
        if prod1+prod2 <1:
            continue

        if prod1:
            routing = route1
            number_of_pallets = prod1
            number_of_steps = route1.shape[0]
        else:
            routing = route2
            number_of_pallets = prod2
            number_of_steps = route2.shape[0]
        for step in range(number_of_steps):
            zone = routing[step]
            output[minute+step,zoneidx[zone]]+=number_of_pallets

    return output
```